# DatagridView Combobox Expanding Issue

Tags: c#, forms, data-binding, datagridview, combobox

I am using Visual Studio 2010, I created a data grid view, which has 2 columns.
text column, the other is combo box Column.

```
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn eqNameClmn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ClmnCabinetOptions;

        this.eqNameClmn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.eqNameClmn.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        this.eqNameClmn.HeaderText = "Cabinet/Mdf";
        this.eqNameClmn.Name = "eqNameClmn";
        this.eqNameClmn.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // ClmnCabinetOptions
        // 
        this.ClmnCabinetOptions.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        this.ClmnCabinetOptions.DataPropertyName = "OptionValue";
        this.ClmnCabinetOptions.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
        this.ClmnCabinetOptions.HeaderText = "Display Options";
        ClmnCabinetOptions.DataSource=
        new object[] {
        "Include Blocks and Cables",
        "Include Blocks",
        "None"};

        this.ClmnCabinetOptions.Name = "ClmnCabinetOptions";
```

I have filled the combo box column with values that the user will have to choose from.
To make my life easier, I created an object, in which I will use to bind to the data grid view, and retrieve whenever the user is finished.

```
public public class NeEquipmentDgvObj {

    public NeEquipment NeEquipment;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeBlocks;
    public bool IncludeCables;
    public string OptionValue { get; set; }
    public NeEquipmentDgvObj(NeEquipment equipmentOb) {

        Name = equipmentOb.EquipmentName;
        NeEquipment = equipmentOb;
        IncludeBlocks = false;
        IncludeCables = false;
    }

}
```

the property OptionValue  will be used so when the combo box is set, this property gets set in the object and I can retrieve the data source of the data grid view after I am finished selecting values in the combo box per item in the list that is binded.

I am running into an issue that whenever the form is loaded, and the items are bounded, the combo box will not expand to show me the items within. if I preset the OptionValue, the combo box value will be set to that OptionValue but will not be changed and the combo box will not expand. What is causing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved, it turns out I had to change few properties.
I set the EnableEditing to True on the DGV, and I set the read only property to false on the entire DGV as well.